# Get FieldArrays Field value to calculate result v.6

Tags: redux-form

```
const renderLists = ({fields}) => {
   return <tbody>
   {fields.map((member, index) =>
       <tr key={index}>
          <td>
             <Field
                 name={`${member}.item`}
                 type="text"
                 component={renderItems}
                 label="Item"/>
          </td>
          <td>
             <Field
                 name={`${member}.unit`}
                 type="number"
                 component={renderField}
                 label="unit"/>
          </td>
          <td>
             <Field
                 name={`${member}.price`}
                 type="number"
                 component="input"
                 label="quantity"/>
          </td>
          <td>
               // Display Unit*Price
          </td>
          <td>
             <button onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}>remove</button>
          </td>
       </tr>
   )}
   <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push({})}>Add Item</button>
   </tbody>
};
```

how to get the value of unit and price for each row and display calculated result on corresponding row.

Comment: https://egghead.io/courses/learn-html5

Answer (score 1):

Use `formValueSelector`:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { formValueSelector } from "redux-form";

const renderList = ({ fields, fieldValues }) => (
  <tbody>
    { fields.map( ( field, index ) => {
      <tr><td>{ fieldValues[ index ] }</td></tr>
    })}
  </tbody>
);

export default connect(state => {
  fieldValues: formValueSelector("formName")(state, "fieldName")
})( renderList );
```

[Documentation available here](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/FormValueSelector.md/)